# jquery slidedown parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm currently using a `<div>` and `<table>` to show the name of some people retrieved from a database. I created an animation with `jquery slidedown` to show extra information of a person once the user clicks on the person's name. But I don't know how to send the info to the animation.

Here I create the table with the records, using a  in the first column :

```
echo "<table width=100%>";
    foreach ($aContactos as $i => $value) {
        echo "<tr>
            <td width=48%><div class=flip_DetalleContacto>$aContactos[$i][0]</div>/td>
            <td width=47%>$aContactos[$i][1]</td>
            <td width=5%>$aContactos[$i][2]</td>
        </tr>";
    }
echo "</table>";
```

And somewhere, in other  position I want to show info from the clicked row :

```
echo "<div class=panel_DetalleContacto> INFO OF THE SELECTED ROW </div>";
```

The Script :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(
    function() {
        var expanded = false;
        // When clicked on the menu-trigger
        $('.flip_DetalleContacto').click(
            function(event) {
                // Slide down menu if hidden
                if (!expanded) {
                    event.stopPropagation();
                    $('.panel_DetalleContacto').slideDown();
                    expanded = true;
                }
                // Slide up menu if shown
                else {
                    $('.panel_DetalleContacto').slideUp();
                    expanded = false;
                }
            }
        );
        // Hide if clicked anywhere on the page
        $(document).click(
            function () {
                if (expanded) {
                    $('.panel_DetalleContacto').slideUp();
                    expanded = false;
                }
            }
        );
        // Prevent slideUp if clicked on the Menu div itself
        // (You can omit this part if you don't need it)
        $('.panel_DetalleContacto').click(
            function(event) {
                event.stopPropagation();
            }
        );
    }
);
</script>
```

How can I get the info to slide down after the name is clicked?

Comment: can you provide Fiddle for it?

Answer (score 0):

dynamically added controls

```
 $(document).on("click", "#id", function () {
 this.slideDown("slow");  
 or     
 $(.classname).slideDown("slow");
 });
```

Statically available controls

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
 $("#id").slideDown("slow");
 or     
 $(.classname).slideDown("slow");
 });
```